# Green fire in Inmarsat-5 Launch

Tags: launch, spacex

The Inmarsat-5 from SpaceX launched earlier today. I was watching the broadcast and noticed a brief green flame during ignition. What caused this? [image]

Comment: That's a beautiful screen shot! If you search for ["green"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22green%22) here you can see that it's been asked already [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15401/12102) and there's a good answer. You can read more [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3002/12102) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the TEA-TEB mixture used to start the engines. The boron in the TEB is responsible for the green flame.